# Is there a software that can only render part of a mesh?

Tags: mesh, cad, surface, 3d-rendering

Is there such a software that can render only part of a mesh, while rendering the whole surface, as shown in the following picture? It will be perfect if it works for triangular mesh. Any help will be appreciated!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqpp0ijrmkm4fiv/nPower-SubD-NURBS-old-man-e1297714632154.jpg

Comment: even Blender has got the Subdivision Surface property, which set to 3-4 shows smooth surface, when you are still working or unchanged mesh.

Comment: @VixinG I'm fine with surface rendering, but I am more interested if I can specify a certain boundary, so that within that boundary the software will also render the mesh, but not the whole mesh. For example in the picture I posted, it only renders the left part of the mesh.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know exactly, but like in Maya, you can select part of object and isolate that selection and then render only the selection (I'm guessing here) see http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/index.html?url=files/Vari_Render_all_or_some_objects_from_a_camera.htm,topicNumber=d30e688156